# FFMPEG not working in php code

Tags: php, linux, video, ffmpeg

I have tried with ffmpeg for video thumbnail creation. 
In windows its working fine, but in Linux(centos) it's not working.

i have tried the following command:

```
 $cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i  /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_videos/".$video."
-ss 00:00:01.435 -f image2 -vframes 1     /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_images/".$videoname."-thumb.jpg";

    echo exec($cmd);
```

The abovecommand is working in the Linux command line and thumbnails are creating in destination folder, i have given static video file.

> But the same command is not working as expected in the php script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably because you're missing the starting `/` on your `-i`.

Comment: Check destination directory permissions

Comment: sorry that's my mistake,i have given '/' in my code,i have updated my code

Comment: destination file folder permissions are 0777 given

Comment: Give me any suggestions i have struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a **new-line** character in your command. Use a single line:

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i  /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_videos/".$video." -ss 00:00:01.435 -f image2 -vframes 1     /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydashboard/sites/default/files/content_images/".$videoname."-thumb.jpg";
```

Also, the `-ss` parameter needs to be before `-i` in order to seek the input file.

Comment: I removed the new-line characters from your command since this breaks the command (notice it's a single line with no "Enter" in it).

Comment: in my code i have written echo exec($cmd) is it correct?

Comment: Php using my own folders